# Pseudonyms and Book signings

Tags: pseudonym

I use a pseudonym and was wondering what the decorum is for setting up a book signing or for signing some in-store copies if I happened to stumble across them.

I assume the stores have some minor hoops to jump through to set up a signing or else any Joe Schmo off the street could come in pretending they're the writer, but I've yet to see any answers for this particular scenario.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

**Talk to the store**

Every bookstore will have an employee who sets up signings, meet and greets, readings, etc.  Tell them you're the author of a book they sell and you're interested in doing that.

Do you have a Fictitious Business Name registered with your county?  If so, that would be enough to prove who you are.  If not, you surely have some paperwork with your pen name.  But chances are they won't ask for proof.

How are you going to cash your royalty checks?  Either they're written to your pen name and you have a FBN for the bank.  Or they're written to your legal name and you have a contact stating the pen name.  Yes?

My spouse and I are in discussion with our local bookstore about this.  My spouse (using his real name) has a published e-comic that will be collected into a physical book after each set of 4 issues.  The bookstore has offered a meet and greet.  Granted, the employee in charge already knows my spouse from their defunct comic book club, but I'd honestly be shocked if they needed proof of identity.